# Airflow context["execution_date"] - Convert datetime format, can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have the following values:

```
fdt = 2016-12-01 00:00:00
(datetime type)

tdt = 3000-01-01 00:00:00
(datetime type)
```

exec_dt is set to this

```
exec_dt = context["execution_date"]
```

and when printed out shows this:

```
exec_dt = 2021-05-19T16:00:00+00:00
(datetime type)
```

I'm trying to run this:

```
 fdt <= exec_dt <= tdt
```

to return a boolean value, but currently its throwing the following error because the formatting of exec_dt is not correct:

> can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: What does the string representation have to do with whether the datetime is offset-naive or offset-aware?

Comment: @BradSolomon I was just trying to get the same format, when I printed out each variable's values they were different and I was trying to get the same format, but that's not correct because its string.

Comment: Include the values and types of `fdt` and `tdt` in your question

Comment: @BradSolomon hello, I've updated my question, to be more precise, could you please help me?